# get numeric column values in data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with many columns and in order to create a loop I want to work with the column number rather than the column name (in order to run Shapiro normality test).

I thought I would get the same results for the following:

```
a=DT[,Total]    
b=DT[,2, with=F]
```

However, the first returns numeric class and the second data frame/data table.
For shapiro.test I need numeric.

Any idea how to use the columns' numbers to get numeric result?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `DT[[2]]` since `DT` is still a list.

Comment: Thanks! That was simple:)

Comment: @RamB you can delete, or self-answer your question, to not leave it open on SO.

Comment: I suggest going through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).